# Angular-ui paging not working on modal

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui, paging

I am not able to make the angular-ui paging work on the modal and I don't get any error. Copied the code from a working paging without modal, but isn't working anymore.

This is my plunker:

```
<a href="https://plnkr.co/edit/5JHKpdmLMVBFlmL22SGC?p=preview">Plunker</a>
```

This was my starting point without modal:

```
<a href="https://plnkr.co/edit/mQUSVxj3PWtZWL0tYD2z?p=preview">Plunker</a>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I am going for a manual paging as I didn't find much info online regarding this.